# One doubt regarding measurable function

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $\phi(x,y)$ be a random variable on the product space $(R,B) \times (S,E)$ and $E|\phi(X,Y)| < \infty$ where $X$ and $Y$ are random vectors taking values in 
$(R,B)$ and $(S,E)$ respectively.

Now in a book it is claimed  since $\phi(x,y)$ is jointly measurable in $(x,y)$ for fixed $x$ it is a measurable function of $y$. I don't understand how does it uses Fubini/Tonelli.

Comment: Do you know about measurability of sections?

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: yes, but for that we need non-negativity/integrability of $\phi$.

Comment: The product $\sigma $- algebra is the coarsest $\sigma$-algebra, such that the projections to the coordinate spaces are measurable morphisms. This implies that the sections of sets are measurable. Now you can also show that the sections of functions are measurable.

Comment: @DimitriosNtalampekos: got it. it is due to the product space.